# POST 400 (Bad Request) Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, post

I'm trying to pass a data from my client to server side script, but my program reply `POST http://localhost:3005/v1/account/login 400 (Bad Request)`, but whenever I try it on postman, it always work properly,

This is my code for requesting post data to my NodeJS server using my ReactJS application:

```
fetch(config.endPoint.login, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        if(response.error_code == 0) {
          console.log(response);

          this.props.history.push("/main");
        } else {
          alert('login failed!');
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('Error\nplease check your network connection and try agian!');
      });
```

well I use that request when I'm creating a react-native app from my previous projects and it works well, so I don't think that there's something wrong about my method of requesting a data to server

This is my controller that handles the api request on that login route

```
// '/v1/account/login'
api.post('/login', passport.authenticate(
    'local', {
        session: false,
        scope: []
    }
), generateAccessToken, respond);
```

And this is my middleware that handles that api requests and response

```
let authenticate = expressJwt({secret: SECRET});

let generateAccessToken = ( req, res, next ) => {

req.token = req.token || {};
req.token = jwt.sign({
    id: req.user.id
}, SECRET, {
    expiresIn: TOKENTIME
});
   next();
}

let respond = (req, res) => {
    Account.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, (err, account) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        let user_token = sha256.x2(Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + account._id + config.serverCode + config.serverKey)
        account.user_token = user_token;

        account.save(err => {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'success',
                error_code: 0,
                user_token: user_token,
                user_id: req.user._id,
                user: req.user.username,
                token: req.token
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And then, I'm having an error saying that `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3005/v1/account/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

So I researched and found to write this code at my `index.js` file

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
```

And now, I'm having an error saying `POST http://localhost:3005/v1/account/login 400 (Bad Request)`

And I researched and see someone says that

> bad request means that you're trying to fetch data from request object using invalid keys. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047482/post-400-bad-request)

but I can't see the wrong data that I'm passing,

I pass data using postman in this format:

```
{
    "username": "yoyo929",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

And it works well,
what's the wrong with my codes?

I'm also seeing this error at my nodejs terminal

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (F:\project\galaxy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at F:\project\galaxy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (F:\project\galaxy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (F:\project\galaxy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (F:\project\galaxy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Comment: can you try with `body: JSON.Stringify({username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})` in the fetch call in React App

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data you are passing to fetch must be stringified, otherwise something like `[object Object]` will be passed in:

```
fetch(config.endPoint.login, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    })
  }).then((response) => {
    if(response.error_code == 0) {
      console.log(response);

      this.props.history.push("/main");
    } else {
      alert('login failed!');
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    alert('Error\nplease check your network connection and try agian!');
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yahh, that's correct, and I tried it earlier, and it didn't work, then I just see and realized that the `this.state.username` is blank because when I'm typing at my input field I'm using `this.setState({email: evt.target.value})`, so my email state is the one who have a value and not that username state, I also learned that if you pass a blank value, it will cause an 400 bad request error